# Accessing filename through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get the filename of an uploaded file through a form. `params` returns data like so:

```
(byebug) pp params
{"enable_test"=>"1",
 "tokens_per_day"=>"0",
 "unlimited_tokens"=>"0",
 "test_scripts_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"seq_num"=>"1.0",
     "script_name"=>
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000007b370c0
       @content_type="application/pdf",
       @headers=
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"assignment[test_scripts_attributes][0][script_name]\"; filename=\"ass5import.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n",
       @original_filename="ass5import.pdf",
       @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151115-5586-patihn.pdf>>,
     "description"=>"",
     "max_marks"=>"2",
     "run_on_submission"=>"0",
     "run_on_request"=>"0",
     "halts_testing"=>"0",
     "display_description"=>"display_after_submission",
     "display_run_status"=>"display_after_submission",
     "display_marks_earned"=>"display_after_submission",
     "display_input"=>"display_after_submission",
     "display_expected_output"=>"display_after_submission",
     "display_actual_output"=>"display_after_submission"}}}
{"enable_test"=>"1", "tokens_per_day"=>"0", "unlimited_tokens"=>"0", "test_scripts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"seq_num"=>"1.0", "script_name"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000007b370c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151115-5586-patihn.pdf>, @original_filename="ass5import.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"assignment[test_scripts_attributes][0][script_name]\"; filename=\"ass5import.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">, "description"=>"", "max_marks"=>"2", "run_on_submission"=>"0", "run_on_request"=>"0", "halts_testing"=>"0", "display_description"=>"display_after_submission", "display_run_status"=>"display_after_submission", "display_marks_earned"=>"display_after_submission", "display_input"=>"display_after_submission", "display_expected_output"=>"display_after_submission", "display_actual_output"=>"display_after_submission"}}}
```

Right now, the code im trying to fix is storing `script_name` as the filename, which is wrong/ I'd like to store the filename instead. How can I access the `@headers` filename?

The code im trying to modify previously accessed it like so, but it seems like this is out dated and no longer works (code is from RoR 3.0)

```
# Filter out test support files that need to be created and updated
    unless testsupporters.nil?
      testsupporters.each_key do |key|
        tfile = testsupporters[key]

        # Check to see if this is an update or a new file:
        # - If 'id' exists, this is an update
        # - If 'id' does not exist, this is a new test file
        tf_id = tfile['id']

        # If only the 'id' exists in the hash, other attributes were not updated
        # so we skip this entry. Otherwise, this test file possibly requires an
        # update
        if !tf_id.nil? && tfile.size > 1

          # Find existing test file to update
          @existing_testsupport = TestSupportFile.find_by_id(tf_id)
          if @existing_testsupport
            # Store test file for any possible updating
            updated_support_files[key] = tfile
          end
        end

        # Test file needs to be created since record doesn't exist yet
        if tf_id.nil? && tfile['file_name']
          updated_support_files[key] = tfile
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't reference `params` anywhere, and there's no way to know what kind of object `techsupporters` is. So I can't tell you exactly how to modify your code.

But from the params you posted, I believe that what you want is `params['test_scripts_attributes']['0']['script_name'].original_filename`.

In the end, the method you're looking for is [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile#original_filename`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html).

From the looks of it, the params could contain anything from zero to multiple files. So be sure to account for that.